# Django use multiple databases

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-admin

I'm trying to make a Django website as a user interface for data I've collected through a scraper. The scraper generates (and constantly updates) a database and I'd like Django to interact with it as well.

I need to run the scraper program often, is there a way I can do this through Django's admin? Like manage the backend that doesn't have to do with Django directly?

Should I merge the databases (scraper and Django)?

Is there a proper way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're looking for what's called an "unmanaged database" in Django - see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/options/#managed) for how to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django [supports multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/multi-db/). You can leave your scraping program/database as is and simply access the database through Django. Set up models as you normally would - but in the `META` field set `managed = False`. This will prevent Django from applying migrations to the databases.

If you find you do want to manage the database through Django models you will need to set up a [routing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing) class to make sure your app only targets the intended database.

Comment: Won't I have problems because my scraper program will write to db while Django will read it? SQLite doesn't support threading (or at least it's bad at it I believe). Would I need to change to something like MySQL?

Comment: I can't comment on scaling, but unless you are doing thousands of operations a second it shouldn't have any issues.